# What causes the lamp above my gas stove to swing like a pendulum when the stove is on?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, oscillators, convection

There is lamp hanging above my gas stove, which when the stove is turned on performs pendulum-like oscillations in an oval trajectory, not unlike the dynamics of Lissajous patterns. The lamp is similar in shape to these ones and hangs exactly above the center of the stove:

[image].

There is some symmetry involved (circular "cross section" of the lamp and hanging above the center of the stove), but I'm not sure how to go about modelling this "heat convection pendulum" to try to understand it's behavior. Is there a missing link between pendulum dynamics and heat convection that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

A column of heated air rising off the stove surface will rise in a straight column for a while, and then switch to a wobbly pattern as cooler air gets mixed in with the rising flow- which then exhibits curlicues and random waviness. It is likely that the hanging lamp is getting gently buffeted by that flow.

To test this, make you a *smoke tracer* by lighting a candle, blowing it out, and holding it over the hot stove so the candle smoke makes the air currents visible as they approach the lampshade- then TAKE PICTURES of the result and share them here tomorrow for all to see!!